# When I delete a selection in photoshop, surroundings will be faded

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Im trying to remove white patches from my photo and set them as transparent. So far I figured out I could add a transparent layer benief]

left picture is after I pressed delete

Comment: I really need help I searched all over the web but I found no solution

Comment: While **you** may see differences immediately, I see very little change which *might* be due to a dark layer under the artwork or a selection which wasn't 100% opaque. A little more effort in describing the problem wouldn't hurt. I see nothing which is "faded".

Comment: actually its the pixels around the selection on the left that look transparent, which led me to assume this is due to feathering

Comment: I want the picture have a transparent background. I did some research on youtube, and it said that you could add a transparent layer under the photo, and after deleting parts of the photo, it will reveal the transparent layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure 'Feather' value is set to zero before hitting the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.

[image]

Comment: It is, the problem still exists.